# Making SVG object integration to work

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, svg

I'm trying to learn more about SVG objects in html documents and I downloaded the files of these example here: [link]http://tomgermeau.com/2014/02/how-designers-can-create-interactive-prototypes-with-illustrator/ but I can't make it to work. the html document returns empty.

I put there these tag:

`<object type="image/svg+xml" data="fruit.svg">Your browser does not support SVG</object>`

But still doesn't work.

here's the code I have in the html file:

`<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.0.min.js"></script>`

```
<script>
    $.get('fruit.svg', function(data) {
    // $.get('fruit_font.svg', function(data) {
    $(document.body).append(data.documentElement);

  // clicking row 1 will show the dialog
  $('#row1').click(function() {
    $('#tooltip').hide();
    // adding 'fast' as a parameter will make it fade
    $('#dialog').fadeIn();

  });

  // dialog close button
  $('#closebutton').click(function() {
    $('#dialog').hide();
  });

  // tooltip logic
  $('#row1').hover(
    function mouseover() {
      $('#tooltip').show();
    }, 
    function mouseleave() {
      $('#tooltip').hide();
    }
  );

});

</script>
```

and the styles:

```
<style>
#row1, #closebutton {
  cursor: pointer;
}
#closebutton {
  opacity: .7;  
}
#closebutton:hover {
  opacity: 1;  
}
</style>
```

Thank you for your support.

Comment: Are you testing this off your local machine, or off a web server?  Does the SVG work if you look at it directly in the browser?  Are you sure the link to the SVG is correct?

Comment: I'm testing on my local machine and off a web server, here [link]http://lisboa.smartmove.pt/SCPWebsite/fruit/fruit.html

All files are in the same directory

Comment: well it says 'failed to load ressource' in the console. maybe your svg is in another folder? what does your .svg file look like?

Comment: My files:
[link]https://www.dropbox.com/sh/iv1wiwhaolrlpl3/AAAw6-oMTpX7tRahGPVLhTvXa?dl=0

I see the svg file in the browser on my local machine but  it doesn't work. On the server, I can't see the image

Comment: In the browser console I see the error: `GET http://lisboa.smartmove.pt/SCPWebsite/fruit/fruit.svg 404 (Not Found)`.  So I think you should check your SVG URL again.